# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisifes the requirements [RASPBIAN OS]

Tags: pip, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to install [dawdreamer](https://github.com/DBraun/DawDreamer) onto my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B (Running the latest 32-bit Raspberry Pi OS with desktop) using the following command:

```
pip install dawdreamer
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirements dawdreamer
ERROR: No matching distribution found for dawdreamer
```

My Raspberry Pi is running Python 3.9.2

I tried cloning the repo and pip installing locally but that didn't work either. I'm also able to pip install other packages – dawdreamer is the only one giving me grief.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if dawdreamer isn't built for Raspberry Pi. When you `pip install dawdreamer`, `pip` looks for viable packages at `https://pypi.org/simple/dawdreamer/`. Inspecting the available packages at that URL, we see:

1. They are all binary wheels (there is no source distribution)
2. The only Linux packages are for x86_64 architecture

So that's why `pip install` doesn't work: there is no version of dawdreamer available for Linux on ARM.

Figuring out why trying to install from a local checkout didn't work would require more information about how it failed. I would suggest opening that as a second question.

Comment: How should a local checkout installation look like? I could've definitely done it incorrectly.

Comment: Open a new question, showing what you tried and how it failed, and we might be able to help out. I've never tried installing dawdreamer myself, so I don't know what sort of dependencies it may have. The errors you're seeing might help provide some suggestions on what steps to try next.